# Understanding Compiler Version Impact on Building R and R Packages

Tags: r, clang, cran, compiler-version

I am currently performing local testing based on rhub images, which requires to install R packages (and other dependencies) from source. I’ve noticed that the compiler versions used in the rhub images are not the same as those used on CRAN.

Specifically, the [`r-hub/fedora-clang-devel`](https://hub.docker.com/r/rhub/fedora-clang-devel) image uses (as of today) **GNU Fortran (GCC) 12.2.1** and **clang version 14.0.5**, while the CRAN flavour [`r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-clang`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_flavors.html#r-devel-linux-x86_64-fedora-clang:%7E:text=clang%20version%2016.0.6%3B%20GNU%20Fortran%2013.2) uses **GNU Fortran 13.2** and **clang version 16.0.6**.

I am trying to understand the potential impact of this difference. Could someone provide some background or explanation on the following:

1. What are the potential effects of using different compiler versions for building R and installing R packages? In general but also specifically for package testing that include source code.
2. Is it necessary to match the compiler versions exactly when building R and installing packages? I understand that it is possible to change the defaults used to install R packages from source by changing `~/.R/Makevars`, but I don't understand the exact effect this has on the behaviour of the R packages with source code and on other (compiled), non-R dependencies.
3. What are the risks or issues that might arise if I update the compiler of the rhub image and install my packages (and their dependencies) with this new compiler version?

I am aware that different compiler versions can lead to performance differences and compatibility issues, but I would like to understand this in more depth.

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems way too broad a question for SO. Package DESCRIPTION files will often specify compiler versions. You should cite specific sections of the R Installation Manual: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html that are confusing. I suppose a narrowed version of this question might get an answer of some sort at the R-devel mailing list or https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-fedora, but I suspect they would  have expected you to have consulted that reference, since the folks are r-devel spend quite a bit of energy making sure it is accurate and up-to-date.